# How do I run a gitlab / github cloned project in eclipse? (When it is not an eclipse project)

Tags: java, eclipse, git

Wanted to get some oppinions here. I've asked a lot of friends for an answer on this and no-one havs ever gotten a good solution to it. I recently cloned a java project from gitlab and have no clue how to run it. I had to import it as a general project because its not an actual eclipse project. But then I have no clue how on earth it was uploaded in this file structure in the first place?

[image: https://gyazo.com/4374da8ab95af54de7dac3b3566aad1b]

Answer (score 0):

In case of very simple project, often you can right click on the source folder (could be more than one) and select "use as source", then you need to add all of the libraries by right cliking on them and using "add to build path".

If it is other kind of project like maven, gradle etc... they have own tasks to eclipse-ize the project, check documentation.

There is no single and straightforward way because there is nothing like one and only valid standard of project structure and/or dependency management.